# Office Online Server not functioning in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-server, office-online-server

I have a SharePoint 2016 Single Server farm up and running, no apparent issues.

I have also installed and configured an Office Online Server w HTTPS on a separate box of its a own.

Ive run the WOPI registration on the SP machine (not on its sql box, as it doesnt appear to be where that should be done)  and everything has been Green Lights.  All expected responses have come back from commands, scripts, etc.

When a user logs into a SharePoint site, none of the office integrations are there.   No option to Add an Office doc, open in browser, etc.  Nothing changed.

I’ve scoured MS and google search for anything Im missing.  And come up empty.  Beyond just formatting the boxes and starting over, Ive done everything.  Looking for any suggestions before I try again from scratch.

Answer (score 3):

Check the OOS box via `Get-OfficeWebAppsFarm` to verify the zone you used during the build (InternalUrl or ExternalUrl). From there, verify your WOPI zone on SharePoint via `Get-SPWOPIZone`. If it doesn't match one of the above, set it approprately. Since you're using SSL, it would be one of these two:

`Set-SPWOPIZone external-https` or `Set-SPWOPIZone internal-https`

Lastly, don't forget your client machines as well as SharePoint need to be able to resolve and access OOS via the URL that was set for OOS.

Comment: Also, if you are using self-signed certs for SSL, make sure your SP server trusts your OOS cert and vice-versa.